# Order by Rest API in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, rest

```
var restURLAuthors = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('GoGreenReport')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,FileRef&$filter=Project_x0020_Name eq '"+$("#ddnProjectName").val()+"'";
```

i want to add order by descending order of items? Where and how to write order by in this code specifically?

Comment: The above code along with other code adds item of attachment of a form to a library, taking project name as primary key , but with same project name multiple attachments are getting saved and when viewed its showing the oldest one, i want to view the latest one?

Answer (score 28):

You should add order by in the REST query itself as below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('GoGreenReport')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,FileRef&$filter=Project_x0020_Name eq '"+$("#ddnProjectName").val()+"'&$orderby=Created desc
```

Here, i have appended `$orderby=Created desc`, you can also use `$orderby=Modified desc` or any other custom field with its internal name. In case if you want the latest one, you can also use `$orderby=ID desc`

Comment: I tried this whole code = var restURLAuthors = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('GoGreenReport')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,FileRef&$filter=Project_x0020_Name eq '"+$("#ddnProjectName").val()+"'&$orderby=ID desc";    BUT this doesnt work, am i doing something wrong? @gautam sheth

Comment: it works for me, i dont think what you are doing is wrong. Log the results in console and check

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments said, it is all done in the URI

#### SharePoint endpoints are ODATA endpoints

- URI Conventions (OData Version 2.0)
  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/
- Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Search has different syntax

- SharePoint Search REST API overview
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8a4f7863-e4c1-4099-9189-a1894db36930%28office.15%29.aspx
- FAST Query Language (FQL) syntax reference
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx

iREST

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i want specific answer to the code line as i have provided, if you could write me the script code itself it would be better.

Comment: i just wanted one specific line of code . Well there's world full of people like you anyways

Comment: That was a good compliment to yourself. i appreciate

Comment: the SharePoint REST API Overview link is going to SharePoint Workflow fundamentals.. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-workflow-fundamentals